# :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm new to proguard, and I do not understand how to solve my problem. It seems easy, but I do not know how to fix it.

**proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ';' in line 51**

And below the error is displayed: Execution failed for task '**:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease**'

This is my 51st line:

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers { public static ; }
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
    # Vungle
-dontwarn com.vungle.**
-dontnote com.vungle.**
-keep class com.vungle.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.*

# GreenRobot
-dontwarn de.greenrobot.event.util.**

# RxJava
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.unsafe.**
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
   rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
   rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode ;
}


-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers { public static ; }
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler { public ; }
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler { public ; }
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers { public static ** test(); }

# MOAT
-dontwarn com.moat.**
-keep class com.moat.** {
   public protected private *;
}




-keep class com.tapjoy.** { *; }
-keep class com.moat.** { *; }
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents();
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.tapjoy.**


-keep public class com.google.gson
-keep class Gson**
-keepclassmembers class Gson** {
    *;
}
-keepattributes Signature, *Annotation*
-keep class com.nativex.** {
    *;
}

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

**This answer solved my problem:**

Use

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {public static <methods>;}
```

in place of

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers { public static ; }
```

**But now a new one has arisen.**

Exception:

`Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.`

This is my warning:

```
 Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
```

And above the big list `Note: .....`

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
```

in place of

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers { public static ; }
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem with this error. But now a new one has arisen.  `Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.`  **This is my warning:**  `Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. ` And above the big list `Note:  ....`. What can I do about it?

Comment: Check properly whether you have added all the library properly in build.gradle of app module .

Comment: Add the libraries from the instructions given in official GitHub page always .

Comment: And there is a thing ,one question may have more than one answer but vice versa is not true always . So think twice before asking such unclear questions . Thank you !

Comment: I added this library to my application [link](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress). Maybe this is a problem because of it? Because it is not official.

Comment: Have u added jitpack to allprojects in build.gradle of your  project . While using any thirdparty library , use the standard proguard code mentioned for that library .

Comment: What does it mean? In the instructions of one of the libraries that I added to the project, there was an instruction to add a line `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`. And the instructions for proguard did not have.  I did not understand what to do. Explain, please.

Comment: Gradle and Proguard are different thing .

Comment: Thank you.
 What to do in those cases when there is no standard proguard code mentioned for that library?

Comment: The problem was that I missed one `Warning`.  I apologize. Thanks for answers.